# In oracle PLSQL how can I update every row based on a join to another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been fighting with this for hours. I essentially have a table, Cats, and I want to update every cat in the table to be called `Mr <Name>`. So insert Mr before.

I can do that pretty easily.

However I want to only update cats that are in Poshtown. I have an Address table, so I can join from `Cat` to `Address` on `AddressId` and then update any where `TownName = 'Poshtown'`

I have tried everything I can think of. I *think* the solution is to use `MERGE INTO`.

So I have tried a lot of variations. It actually worked for some of my queries (or at least, didn't error). But not this one.

```
 MERGE INTO Cat c
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT c.catId, a.addressId
  FROM Cat c
  INNER JOIN Address a ON c.addressId = a.addressId
  WHERE a.Townname = 'Poshtown'
) t ON (c.catId = t.catId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET c.Name = 'Mr. ' || c.Name
```

I get the error:

> ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
> ORA-06512: at line 4
> 30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
> *Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
> activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
> *Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

I am not an oracle person whatsoever but sadly I have to run this query. My understanding of what this should be doing, is looking at each individual cat, and then updating each one. So I can't understand why I am getting this error. I have tried some variations. And this might not even be the right way to solve my problem, but it's all I've been able to scrape together.

Any ideas?

If it makes a difference, the tables don't have any keys set on them. The catId is unique within the dataset (I checked) but a cat may have multiple addresses. I put a DISTINCT in which I thought might cater for that, since it's not actually touching the address table, but I am not sure if that's right.

Comment: Please post sample data.  The current query, as written, does not make sense, as there is no way to correlate a cat to its specific address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that you still have duplicates, which means you might have at least one cat with multiple address *in Poshtown*. That would mean a `catId` still appears more than once.

As you don't use the address you might just be able to remove that from the inner select list:

```
MERGE INTO Cat c
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT c.catId
  FROM Cat c
  INNER JOIN Address a ON c.addressId = a.addressId
  WHERE a.Townname = 'Poshtown'
) t ON (c.catId = t.catId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET c.Name = 'Mr. ' || c.Name
```

But you can also use `exists` which is simpler:

```
UPDATE Cat c
SET c.Name = 'Mr. ' || c.Name
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT null
  FROM Address a
  WHERE a.addressId = c.addressId
  AND a.Townname = 'Poshtown'
)
```

Then it doesn't matter how many addresses match, as long as at least one does.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aglhH6ej)

Comment: Thanks, that second example makes sense and is simple. I guess my DISTINCT doesn't work when there are multiple addresses as you're not getting distinct CatIds since it's distincting the entire row, and that's what's causing it?

Comment: Yes - the combinations of cat and address will only appear once, but within those results the same cat can still appear more than once (with different Poshtown addresses).

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you for the fiddle as well that is remarkable!

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to MERGE against a matching criteria that is non-unique. I suggest rewriting your query as a simple UPDATE. Since you cannot have JOINs in an UPDATE statement, you would have to do something like:

```
UPDATE Cat c
    SET c.Name = 'Mr. ' || c.Name
    WHERE
        c.catId IN (
            SELECT
                a.catId
            FROM
                Address a
            WHERE
                a.Townname = 'Poshtown'
        );
```